# what is diff in @Injectable() and @Inject

Tags: angular, inject, injectable

I am working on angular2 I have created  service  and inject those service  using @Inject in component.  I am confuse with the use of  @Injectable() in service itself and what diff it makes.

Comment: Learn more here:[Dependency Injection in Angular 2](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/05/18/dependency-injection-in-angular-2.html) and in [official docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html)

Answer (score 5):

**@Inject()** is a manual mechanism for letting Angular 2 know that a parameter needs to be injected

**@Injectable()** lets Angular 2 know that a class can be used with the dependency injector. `@Injectable() is not strictly required` if the class has other Angular 2 decorators on it. What is important is that any class that is going to be injected with Angular 2 is decorated.

However best practice is to decorate injectables with @Injectable(), as it is makes more sense to the reader.